# Unable to surf with Ease due Certificate Requirement or virus

Tags: firefox, virus, malware, windows-firewall, trojan

I am trying to surf the internet but for any link which I type or enter, I get the following message :

```
This Connection is Untrusted

You have asked Firefox to connect securely to accounts.google.com, but we can't     confirm that your connection is secure.

Normally, when you try to connect securely, sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified.
What Should I Do?

If you usually connect to this site without problems, this error could mean that someone is trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't continue.
```

On clicking the option of `Technical Details`, I get the following message :

```
accounts.google.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate has expired. The certificate will not be valid until 25-02-2014 20:49. The current time is 22-08-2009 14:42. (Error code: sec_error_expired_issuer_certificate)
```

I dont know if it because of some kind of virus or anything. But I am about to blow my top with anger because of the certificate issue popping up every time I go to any site. Can someone please help me out ?? Is it because of some virus which tracking my browsing or stealing the cookies ?? Thanks.

Comment: If there's a 'technical details' option, can you select that and paste the results here?

Comment: Check your time and date settings

Comment: yeah I rectified my date settings .. I think this solved my issue. Thanks. But can u tell me the reason as to why there was an error because of wrong date and time ?

Comment: As stated in the technical details,  Google's certificate is valid only from 25-02-2014. Since your date settings were wrong, the certificate wasn't yet valid and so was considered as a forged certificate.

Comment: @Scandalist, please put your comment in as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your date and time settings are correct. It is important that the clock of your computer and the server are in sync for certificates to function.